# How do I draw thick lines in XNA 4.0?

Tags: xna-4.0

I can draw some curves using this:

```
GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>
           (PrimitiveType.LineStrip, Points, 0, count);
```

Now I try to set the `PointSize` to make the line thicker but I can only find a solution for XNA 3.0 using:

```
GraphicsDevice.RenderState.PointSize
```

How can I make my lines thicker in XNA 4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XNA 4 does not support point sprites, which is (I believe) all that PointSize is for; for some rationale, see [Shawn Hargreaves' blog post on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/22/point-sprites-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx). The short version is that D3D10+ does not support them, and continuing to expose them in XNA restricts options for eventually moving XNA's underpinnings to a newer D3D version.

While it's not a decision that was [met with universal praise](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/79057/478840.aspx), it's not the end of the world because you can simulate the effects yourself. It just requires more work. Fortunately, there are third-party solutions to do so that already exist -- something like the [RoundLine](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=roundline) library might serve your needs, or you can see [this blog post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/manders/lines-2d-thick-rounded-line-segments-for-xna-programs) about a similar technique (probably actually the same one RoundLine uses).